# Upload data in string format in R

Tags: r, string, read.table

How is it possible to import data in R in format string? I have tried with read.csv and read.table but it is uploaded as a character, and I need it as a string

Comment: What does your data look like and what exactly did you try? It's unclear exactly what you want here. Maybe `readLines` can help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need `readChar`, e.g.,

```
readChar(fileName, file.info(fileName)$size)
```